# Selenium chromedriver userprofile - DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, user-profile

I am trying to open the Selenium Chromedriver with a predefined userprofile. The problem is that sometimes I want to run this in visible-mode while using chrome on my own in the meantime - which I cant get to work.

Chrome version: Version 114.0.5735.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:/Users/<User>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory={}".format("Profile 5"))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Upon execution, chrome opens and I see that I am logged into userprofile 5. However after about two seconds. I get the following exception (while the opened selenium browser keeps open):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

When switching into headless mode via

```
options.add_argument('headless')
```

everything works apparently (at least I dont get an exception).

Also when opening in non-headless, but without userprofile everything works.

Is there a way to open a non-headless selenium chromedriver with a user-profile while still being able to regularly browse in the normal chrome browser?
Thanks for any help!